# Alertify does not stop for prompt

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, prompt, alertify

So I have these lines of code:

```
$('td').click(function (e) {
    var test = "....";
    var test2 = "....";
    var test3 = "....";
    SuppressWarning(test, test2, test3);
});

function SuppressWarning(test, test2, test3)
{
  var reason = prompt("Why are you suppressing this warning?");
  if(reason != "")
  {
    //do something
  }
```

When the system runs, it stops at the prompt and does not proceed to the if statement unless the user interacts.
However, I want to customise the alert box so I decided to use alertify.js .

So I have now ended up with this code:

```
$('td').click(function (e) {
var test = "....";
var test2 = "....";
var test3 = "....";
SuppressWarning(test, test2, test3);
});

function SuppressWarning(test, test2, test3)
{
var reason = alertify.prompt("Message", function (e, str) {
if (e) {
    // user clicked "ok"
} else {
    // user clicked "cancel"
}
}, "Default Value");

if(reason != "")
  {
    //do something
  }
```

My issue is that when the system runs, it does not stop at the prompt; It just goes to the if statement without and does the rest. Why is that? Why does it not stop at the prompt so that the user can type in something? How can I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Your code probably wants to be inside your function for when it executes. Execution doesn't pause, the prompt is being fired asynchronously. You probably want if(str!= "") inside your function.

Comment: This isn't your issue but I also noticed that your have prompt(message, function) instead of prompt(message, value, function); Maybe try adding "" (empty string) as your default value? For best practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`prompt` is native to the browser and stop the current flow of the code, just like an alert box or confirm. On the other hand, alertify doesn't. The script will not stop if alertify is triggered.

That's why alertify accept a callback as argument. The `function(e, str)` is triggered after the user press `ok` or `cancel`. The `str` argument is what the user inputed. Just move your condition inside that callback:

```
alertify.prompt("Message", function (e, str) {
    if (e) {
        // user clicked "ok"
        if(str != "")
        {
            //do something
        }
    } else {
        // user clicked "cancel"
    }
}, "Default Value");
```

Comment: I will give it a try and comment back again! Thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: Unfortunately this did not do it. The program does the exact same thing as before. The prompt appears for a second or two and then goes away before the user can even type anything in or click on okay/cancel. It seems like the function e is never called as I am doing a console.log after the if (e) and nothing gets written in the console. Any ideas?

Comment: @Zez3 This code is working : http://jsfiddle.net/gd883hqj/ (Need to click run every time the alert box appear). Your problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: Yes you were right from the first time! I managed to get it working. Thank you!